# Unranked trees grammars?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, trees, tree-grammars

Ranked alphabet is very often used in Ranked Trees definition, like [here](http://www.labri.fr/perso/ogauwin/talks/tree-automata.pdf) for instance. In that example for given set $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$ ranks assigned by arity function $ar : \Sigma\rightarrow\mathcal{N}$ as:

$ar(a)=2, ar(b)=2, ar(c)=1$.

And Ranked Tree over $\Sigma$ is defined as:

$T_{\Sigma_r}$, the set of ranked trees, is the smallest set of terms $f(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ such that: $f\in\Sigma_r$, $k = ar(f)$, and $t_i\in T_{\Sigma_r}$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$.

The tree in this example looks like:

```
       b
     /   \
    a     b
   / \   / \
  b   c c   c
 / \
c   c
```

But what about trees like that?

```
       b
     /   \
    a     b
   / \   / \
  b   c c   c
  |   |
  c   a
```

This is also valid tree, but it is obviously is unranked.

My question: do any research regarding *unranked alphabet trees* exist?

What I've found so far is related only to [logic for unranked trees](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0606062.pdf).

Comment: If the arity of a particular symbol varies, then it's not a ranked tree. In a ranked tree the number of children depends only on the symbol. This probably makes things easier, and is "without loss of generality" since you can "annotate" each symbol with its arity.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you, that what I expected, that with variable arity it is not ranked tree anymore. But what about general theory of tree-automata and tree-grammars? Can I redefine all these things without usage of fixed arity? (I feel I can, I simply do not see any troubles). What kind of difficulties I can meet?

Comment: May be it is better to split question on two (first part is already answered by @YuvalFilmus), second part: can we redefine all tree-automata and tree-grammars theory w/o ranked alphabets?

Comment: You probably can (as long as the arity is bounded), but there really isn't that much difference. It's equivalent to annotating each vertex with its degree.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus As I don't want "to invent the bicycle", may be you know any existent attempts (papers) where such definitions w/o ranking are given? Because currently I fill that there are some unknown reasons why ranked trees (only) are used in tree languages theory

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my area, so I can't help you any further.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @Raphael I fill that question it self should be reformulated

Comment: Your question is of the form "Why does this model have to be this way?". The answer is always the same: it *doesn't*. It is one model that serves a specific purpose. Other models can be different. Look at regular trees, for instance. What are advantages of fixed arities? Well, describing families of such trees is simpler, and they are easier to count.

Comment: Not exactly, but I've reformulated my question

Comment: @YuvalFilmus in any case thank you, you helped a lot

Comment: You want to read [TATA](http://tata.gforge.inria.fr/).

Comment: @Raphael I've read it. They build their theory based on ranked trees.

Comment: Regular tree languages definitely contain unranked trees, so I'm not sure what you want. Maybe Flajolet's simple families? There, every symbol can have inifinitely many allowed degrees/ranks.

Comment: @Raphael the question is in accurate set of definitions. In TATA book they started from definition of ranked alphabet and ranked ordered trees. So I suppose imply usage of ranked trees through all book further. If you know published works with this strong set of definitions: from unranked trees to grammars for them - it will be the accepted answer. I'm looking exactly for existent works, because otherwise I could describe it all by my self.

Comment: Maybe you should read further than the first few sections before claiming to know what the whole book contains. Regarding definitions, it seems trivial to write the definitions yourself. What are you really after? Which kind of results are you looking for?

Comment: Dear @Raphael, it's hard to say on which basis you did such conclusion, that I've read only "first few sections" of that book. But let me put a quote from there, p. 13: *"In Chapter 8 we drop the restriction for ranked trees that the label of a node determines the number of successors of this node, so we consider the model of unranked ordered trees"*. But in Ch.8 they do not provide formal definition of tree grammars for unranked trees. What I am looking for - any existent set of formal definitions  of tree grammars (RTG&CFTG) for unranked trees, to make reference to these works.